# How to split a pandas data frame into multiple data frames based on ID?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this data in a single csv file that have multiple headings of ID, Product, etc. I want the last value (last row) of each set. All other rows are to be deleted. Can someone help me with a script to do so? The data looks like this:

| ID | Product | Fat | SNF | Protein |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 365 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 4.08 | 8.52 | 3.19 |
| 365 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 4.04 | 8.52 | 3.2 |
| 365 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 0.026 | 0.004 | 0.009 |
| 365 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 4.06 | 8.52 | 3.2 |
| ID | Product | Fat | SNF | Protein |
| 465 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 3.73 | 8.81 | 3.06 |
| 465 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 3.72 | 8.8 | 3.08 |
| 465 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 0.004 | 0.008 | 0.012 |
| 465 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 3.73 | 8.81 | 3.07 |
| ID | Product | Fat | SNF | Protein |
| 1465 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 4.08 | 8.52 | 3.15 |
| 1465 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 4.04 | 8.52 | 3.16 |
| 1465 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 0.026 | 0.004 | 0.006 |
| 1465 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 4.06 | 8.52 | 3.15 |

What I want to get is this, I mean the last row of each set:

| ID | Product | Fat | SNF | Protein |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 365 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 4.06 | 8.52 | 3.2 |
| 465 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 3.73 | 8.81 | 3.07 |
| 1465 PB 11.11.20 | Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016 | 4.06 | 8.52 | 3.15 |

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df.loc[df.eq(df.columns).all(1).shift(-1, fill_value=True)]
```

Output:

```
                  ID                     Product   Fat   SNF Protein
3    365 PB 11.11.20  Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016  4.06  8.52     3.2
8    465 PB 11.11.20  Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016  3.73  8.81    3.07
13  1465 PB 11.11.20  Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016  3.95  8.44    3.15
```

---

**Explanation**: Code can be broken down like this:

```
meta_rows = df.eq(df.columns).all(1)
```

checks for the meta rows, that is all the cells in the rows are equal to the header. If the first row in your sample data is **not** the column names, you can use:

```
meta_rows = df.eq(df.iloc[0]).all(1)
```

Now, you want the rows before these rows, so we shift the meta row marker up:

```
marker = meta_rows.shift(-1, fill_value=True)
```

and then finally use bolean indexing to get these rows:

```
df[marker]
```

Comment: ah understand the source data now, nice answer mate.

Comment: this is useful. Solved my problem :)

Comment: This worked. But still there are some rows like:
ID                     Product   Fat   SNF Protein

Comment: Anyways, I deleted them manually, they were not too much :)

Comment: @HuzaifaArshad you can also do `df[marker & (~meta_rows)]`.

Answer (score 2):

you can groupby and last :

```
df = df.groupby(['ID'],as_index=False).last()
>>>df

ID                  Product                     Fat     SNF     Protein
365 PB 11.11.20     Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016  4.06    8.52    3.2
465 PB 11.11.20     Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016  3.73    8.81    3.07
1465 PB 11.11.20    Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016  3.95    8.44    3.15
```

if there is unwanted rows after that operations what containing the columns name add:

```
df = df[df['ID'] !='ID']
```

**UPDATE**
note that despite this solution seems strightforward its preformance is arouns 2 times slower then @Quang Hoang's answer, so its a tradeoff of readability and performance...

i would choose readability because to me groupby seems simpler to understand... but it depends on the size of the dataset

Comment: nice answer. I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

You can first group the DataFrame based on `ID` , then iterate over the groups

```
df_grp = df.groupby(by=['ID'])

 res = []
    
for group in df_grp:
    imm_df = group[1].iloc[[:, -1]] ### returns the last row
    res += [imm_df]
        
final_df = pd.concat(res,axis=0)
```

You can further change `iloc range` to fetch a range of rows if needed

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be better to first split the CSV file into separate CSV files, one for each "chunk" of data, so that loading each of them with `pandas` becomes trivial.

This is a possible script to do the splitting, using [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```py
import re
import more_itertools as mitt


HEADER_PATTERN = re.compile(r"^ID,Product,Fat,SNF,Protein$")


with open("data.csv") as file:
    lines = iter(file.readline, "")
    chunks = mitt.split_before(lines, HEADER_PATTERN.match)
    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        with open(f"data{i}.csv", "w") as output:
            output.writelines(chunk)
```

Replace `"data.csv"` with the actual filename. This saves each of the chunks in files `data0.csv`, `data1.csv`, and so on.

Once that's done, you can simply load each of the chunks separately and extract the last row of each:

```py
import itertools
import pandas as pd

# load each chunk
chunks = []
for i in itertools.count():
    try:
        chunk = pd.read_csv(f"data{i}.csv")
        chunks.append(chunk)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        break


# extract the last row of each
last_rows = pd.concat([df.iloc[-1:] for df in chunks])
```

Then:

```py
>>> last_rows
               ID                     Product   Fat   SNF  Protein
365   PB 11.11.20  Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016  4.06  8.52     3.20
465   PB 11.11.20  Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016  3.73  8.81     3.07
1465  PB 11.11.20  Fresh Milk Monitoring 2016  3.95  8.44     3.15
```

Comment: I will try this :)

Comment: Tried this, but the drawback is, it changed the data values Like the Fat, SNF, Proteins.

Comment: @HuzaifaArshad My bad, the slice should have been `[-1:]` and not `[-2:-1]`, should be fixed now :)